# BottomNavigationBar окраска иконок

Tags: android, material-design, material-ui

Я делаю простенькое приложение под андроид, для навигации использую bnb, очень удобный способ навигации, но возникает проблема:
Все иконки в bnb красятся под цвет 
android:colorAccent
В теме активити. Я же хочу, что бы иконки не красились, как это сделать ?
P.s. понимаю, что не рекомендуется так делать, но в моем случае это исключение, дизайн будет намного интереснее без покраски иконок

Answer (score 0):

Есть два таких параметра у `BottomNavigationView`:

```
navigation.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

поставьте нужный цвет и должно сработать

Comment: Вы не поняли меня, картинка сама по себе содержит несколько цветов, а при покраске, они все становятся одного цвета. Мне нужно, что бы окраски не было

Comment: @SokolSokolinskiy тогда  попробуйте navigation.setItemIconTintList(null);